# How to pass data from originalEvent through an event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, events, mouseevent

I need to pass `originalEvent: MouseEvent { ... }` through an event object. Usually you can do it like this:

```
$('#name').trigger({
  type: 'mousedown',
  clientX: 115,
  clientY: 20
);
```

Unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
$('#name').trigger({
  type: 'mousedown',
  clientX: 115,
  clientY: 20,
  originalEvent: MouseEvent {
    isTrusted: true,
    clientX: 115,
    clientY: 20,
    layerX: 115,
    layerY: 20,
    pageX: 115,
    pageY: 20,
    screenX: 115,
    screenY: 20,
    x: 115,
    y: 20
  },
  pageX: 115,
  pageY: 20
});
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Expected '}' to end an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a syntax problem. You need to call the [constructor of `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) with the `new` keyword. You also need to provide the first argument as the type of MouseEvent being raised, and the second argument is then the object which contains the properties of the event; I used `click` in the below example, but this can easily be changed.

Also note that `isTrusted` is a readonly property which you cannot set programmatically.

```js
$('#name').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.originalEvent);
}); 

$('#name').trigger({
  type: 'mousedown',
  clientX: 115,
  clientY: 20,
  originalEvent: new MouseEvent('click', {
    clientX: 115,
    clientY: 20,
    layerX: 115,
    layerY: 20,
    pageX: 115,
    pageY: 20,
    screenX: 115,
    screenY: 20,
    x: 115,
    y: 20
  }),
  pageX: 115,
  pageY: 20
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="name">Name</button>
```

Comment: Worked just fine :)!